# What is the difference between "any" and "a/an"?

Tags: articles, determiners

I have a sentence

> There isn’t ------ egg on the table.

Should the gap have *any* or *an*? What's the difference?

Comment: Do you mean a whole egg or a piece of one (cooked or uncooked)?

Comment: What @Shoe said. Without that context, there is no question.

Comment: [correction: Can you help me **with **x?]

Comment: WIth all due respect, I think you need to go and find some English lessons, online or on tape. This is a very basic question and shows that your English is not even intermediate level.

Comment: tks for your advice - Lambie - My teacher asked me to choose one of two anwers without the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry Stockfish decided to pull his inspiring answer.

You may or may not expect many assorted eggs on the table. You may have been told that the table is where *the* egg was placed. Saying "There is not *an* egg" would be fine. If you had expected to find more than one egg then saying *an egg* would be a good way to emphasize your surprise. As would saying "There is not *a single* egg on that table".

If you were told that the table was covered in cooked/fried/scrambled etc. egg*s* then finding a clean table  you could say "There isn't any egg on this table." Looking for a related food stain on your shirt you might say "There isn't any egg on my shirt".

"Egg" may be found as the singular in the shell or in the plural as the processed meal. As such it is not the best word to explore the *a* versus *an* question.

Comment: I don't *think* my edit to the question has invalidated your answer, but this comment is merely to inform you of that possibility.

Comment: @A. Leach; Thanks for letting me know. Unless I am mistaken I think you removed parts of the question that helped with the context. Making a question shorter is not usually a proper way to edit a question.

Comment: No: actually I added "What's the difference". Have a look at the [edit history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/545181/revisions). There was no context at all.

Comment: Got it. Well done.

Comment: tks so much both of you, My writing skill is so bad that I have to learn English everywhere.